# External monitor (Samsung Odyssey G9) does not respond until restart Macbook Pro (16 inch 2019) even using CalDigit TS4

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I believe now I have tried every possibile solution to get my Macbook Pro 16 inch 2019 to work with the Samsung Odyssey G9 (LC49G97TSSNXDC).

Well, it kind of works: when I first start my Macbook, if the CalDigit TS4 is connected to the one lucky thunderbolt port (which seems randomly chosen and varies for no good reason) and no other peripherals are attached to the TS4.
If by any chance I need to undock the macbook and then come back to the dock, the screen will not work until the macbook restarts.

That also happens without the CalDigit dock: I've tried a multitude of good quality DisplayPort 1.4 to USC-C cables and adapters, but the one common point among all solutions is that at some point, the Macbook will stop recognizing the monitor's existence until a system restart.
This drives me insane, as I constantly work with a multitude of apps and tabs open and it is very disruptive to my workflow.

Could anybody point me out to a working solution, or at least a way to reset the thunderbolt port whitout restarting the system?

Comment: Please edit your question or put in the comments the _specific_ Samsung device you're connecting. Looking at the [Samsung site](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/gaming/49-odyssey-g9-gaming-monitor-lc49g97tssnxdc/) for 'Odyssey G9' gives three different G9 models and specs.

Comment: To clarify: the monitor will stop showing up at all after a while, including in System Report -> Hardware -> Displays? If so, can you try: 1. Updating your monitor's firmware; I know there was a bug with older firmwares and docks that would cause flaky behavior (although I'd expect it to still work with the USB-C cables.) 2. Using gfxCardStatus to force the dGPU on? I find that on my 16" MBP (2019) external displays sometimes don't work unless I manually force the dGPU on.

Comment: @JMY1000 Correct. If I disconnet the macbook from the TS4 dock, when I reconnect it will recognize the dock and all other peripherals connected to it, but the monitor does not appear anywhere, including the Displays preference pane or even the displays section in system report. I've installed gfxCardStatus and set it to all diferent settings, but no luck in getting it to reconnect.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you try updating the monitor firmware and let us know if the error is still occurring?

Comment: the monitor is updated to firmware M- T9549GGAA-1019.0. Doesn't seem to have a new on on sansungs website. The TS4 is updated to firmware 39.1 and also has the PD firmware updated to version 4208 (all per caldigit's recommendations)

Comment: I see 1023.7 on the Samsung website on [this ridiculously annoying to find page](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/?model=N0054075&modelCode=LC49G97TSSNXDC); maybe give that a try? It's a bit of a long shot but it's probably the best path.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, but it seems the 1023.7 is only on the page for a different model number (LS49CG954SNXZA). Mine (LC49G97TSSNXDC ) is still stuck on 1019.0. I contacted Caldigit support on the matter as well. Theis reply is something like "it's the monitor's fault". Lot's of other users complaining about the G9 under mac OS

Comment: I'm having problems with my Macbook Pro 16", late 2019 too. It's really annoying. Sometimes it works, then it stops and reboot, SMC reset, etc., doesn't seem to work for a while. I'm using a a Samsung Odyssey G9, model number LS49AG950NUXEN . Latest firmware: Version 1015.0,17 oct.. 2023. I'm using a USB-C to DisplayPort cable (8K). Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: So far the best for me was to ditch the Caldigit TS4 dock and use just the usb-c to Display Port cable. I got [this one](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08B3XNZGS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1) for pretty cheap.